# apt-get: you have held broken packages

Tags: apt, dependencies, libraries

Everything was working normally, but now libstdc++ seems to be broken. So I try to reinstall it. Things like:

```
sudo apt-get remove stdc++
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
```

don't help. And what I have:

```
$ sudo apt-get install stdc++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libsfstdc++6-dbg-armhf-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-arm64-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++5-dbg-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-pic-arm64-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libx32stdc++6-4.4-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-powerpc-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'xstdcmap' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-dbg-armel-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-4.8-dev' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-arm64-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libsfstdc++6-4.7-dev-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-pic-arm64-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.5-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libx32stdc++-4.8-dev' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-dbg-arm64-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-4.3-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-pic-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-dev-arm64-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.2-dbg-arm64-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib32stdc++6-4.4-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-dev-armel-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-4.0-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.3-dbg-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-4.6-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.1-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.4-dbg-armel-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-4.8-pic-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.4-doc' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++5-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib32stdc++6' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-pic' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-dbg-arm64-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-pic-armhf-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++5-3.3-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libx32stdc++6-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++-4.8-dev-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libx32stdc++6-4.5-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-dev-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-dev-powerpc-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-dev-armel-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-4.8-doc' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.0-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libhfstdc++6-dbg-armel-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libhfstdc++6-armel-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.6-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-4.2-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib32stdc++6-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-4.8-pic-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.4-dbg-arm64-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++5-3.3-dbg-armel-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib32stdc++6-4.5-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.5-dbg-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-4.1-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.0-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-dbg-powerpc-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-4.7-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.6-dbg-armel-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.6-dev' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-dbg-powerpc-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-pic-powerpc-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.5-doc' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-4.8-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-4.8-dev-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libx32stdc++6-4.0-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-dev-arm64-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib32stdc++-4.8-dev' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libx32stdc++6-4.6-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.6-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.0-dbg-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-dev-arm64-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-4.1-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.1-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.1-dbg-armel-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++5-3.3-dbg-arm64-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libhfstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armel-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++5-3.3-doc' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.6-dbg-arm64-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'pd-libstdcpp' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib32stdc++6-4.0-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-pic-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib32stdc++6-4.6-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-4.2-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++5-dbg-armel-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++5-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++3.0-dev' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-dev' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-pic-powerpc-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-4.7-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.0-doc' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.6-doc' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-dev-armhf-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libhfstdc++6-4.7-dev-armel-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-powerpc-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libx32stdc++6-4.1-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-dev-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.5-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.1-dbg-arm64-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libx32stdc++6-4.7-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.2-dbg-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-4.0-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-pic-arm64-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libsfstdc++6-4.8-dbg-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.3-dbg-armel-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.2-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.8-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++5-3.3-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++5-dbg-arm64-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-arm64-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-dbg-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libx32stdc++6-4.7-dev' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib32stdc++6-4.1-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-dev-armel-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib32stdc++6-4.7-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-4.3-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-4.6-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.1-doc' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-doc' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.4-pic' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-dev' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-armhf-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.4-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib32stdc++6-4.7-dev' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-pic-armhf-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libx32stdc++6-4.2-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.3-dbg-arm64-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-dbg-armhf-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-dev-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libx32stdc++6-4.8-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.4-dbg-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++2.8-dev' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++5-doc' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.5-dbg-armel-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-dev-powerpc-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-4.8-pic' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.3-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-4.8-dev-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-armel-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++2.10-dev' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib32stdc++6-4.2-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-armel-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-4.5-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib32stdc++6-4.8-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-dev-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-pic-armel-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-4.4-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-dbg-armel-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libhfstdc++6-armel-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libsfstdc++6-armhf-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.2-doc' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.0-dbg-armel-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.3-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-4.8-pic-arm64-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++5-3.3-dbg-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.5-dbg-arm64-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libx32stdc++6-4.3-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.6-dbg-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libx32stdc++6' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-dev-arm64-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++2.9-dev' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armel-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-pic-armel-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-doc' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-arm64-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.4-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-4.8-dev-arm64-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++5' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-4.4-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib32stdc++6-4.3-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.0-dbg-arm64-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++2.9-glibc2.1-dev' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libsfstdc++-4.8-dev-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-4.7-dev-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.1-dbg-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-4.5-dbg' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-dev-armel-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.4-dev' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libsfstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.2-dbg-armel-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.2-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.3-doc' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libsfstdc++6-armhf-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.6-pic' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-dev-armhf-dcv1' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-dbg-powerpc-cross' for regex 'stdc+'
Note, selecting 'lib64stdc++6-powerpc-cross' instead of 'lib64stdc++6-powerpc-dcv1'
Note, selecting 'libhfstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armel-cross' instead of 'libhfstdc++6-dbg-armel-dcv1'
Note, selecting 'libhfstdc++6-armel-cross' instead of 'libhfstdc++6-armel-dcv1'
Note, selecting 'libsfstdc++6-armhf-cross' instead of 'libsfstdc++6-armhf-dcv1'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-4.8-pic-arm64-cross' instead of 'libstdc++-pic-arm64-dcv1'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-4.8-pic-armhf-cross' instead of 'libstdc++-pic-armhf-dcv1'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++-4.8-pic-powerpc-cross' instead of 'libstdc++-pic-powerpc-dcv1'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armel-cross' instead of 'libstdc++6-dbg-armel-dcv1'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-dev-arm64-cross' instead of 'libstdc++6-dev-arm64-dcv1'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-dev-armel-cross' instead of 'libstdc++-dev-armel-cross'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-dev-armel-cross' instead of 'libstdc++-dev-armel-dcv1'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-dev-armel-cross' instead of 'libstdc++6-dev-armel-dcv1'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-dev-armhf-cross' instead of 'libstdc++6-dev-armhf-dcv1'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-dev-powerpc-cross' instead of 'libstdc++6-dev-powerpc-dcv1'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-pic-arm64-cross' instead of 'libstdc++6-pic-arm64-dcv1'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-pic-armel-cross' instead of 'libstdc++6-pic-armel-dcv1'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-pic-armhf-cross' instead of 'libstdc++6-pic-armhf-dcv1'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-4.7-pic-powerpc-cross' instead of 'libstdc++6-pic-powerpc-dcv1'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-arm64-cross' instead of 'libstdc++6-arm64-dcv1'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-armel-cross' instead of 'libstdc++6-armel-dcv1'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-armhf-cross' instead of 'libstdc++6-armhf-dcv1'
Note, selecting 'libstdc++6-powerpc-cross' instead of 'libstdc++6-powerpc-dcv1'
lib32stdc++-4.8-dev is already the newest version.
lib32stdc++-4.8-dev set to manually installed.
lib32stdc++6 is already the newest version.
lib32stdc++6 set to manually installed.
libstdc++-4.8-dev is already the newest version.
libstdc++-4.8-dev set to manually installed.
libstdc++6 is already the newest version.
libx32stdc++-4.8-dev is already the newest version.
libx32stdc++-4.8-dev set to manually installed.
libx32stdc++6 is already the newest version.
libx32stdc++6 set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib32stdc++6-4.6-dbg : Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-4.4-dbg but 4.4.7-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
 lib32stdc++6-4.7-dbg : Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-4.4-dbg but 4.4.7-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
                        Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-4.6-dbg but 4.6.4-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
 lib32stdc++6-4.8-dbg : Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-4.4-dbg but 4.4.7-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
                        Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-4.6-dbg but 4.6.4-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
                        Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-4.7-dbg but 4.7.3-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 lib64stdc++6-4.8-dbg-powerpc-cross : Conflicts: lib64stdc++6-4.7-dbg-powerpc-cross but 4.7.3-1ubuntu1cross0.7 is to be installed
 libstdc++-4.8-doc : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-doc but 4.4.7-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
                     Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.6-doc but 4.6.4-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
                     Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-doc but 4.7.3-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.6-dbg : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-dbg but 4.4.7-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.6-doc : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-doc but 4.4.7-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.7-dbg : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-dbg but 4.4.7-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
                      Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.6-dbg but 4.6.4-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.7-doc : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-doc but 4.4.7-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
                      Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.6-doc but 4.6.4-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.8-dbg : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-dbg but 4.4.7-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
                      Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.6-dbg but 4.6.4-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-dbg but 4.7.3-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-arm64-cross : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-arm64-cross but 4.7.3-1ubuntu1cross0.6 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-armhf-cross : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armhf-cross but 4.7.3-7ubuntu3cross1.84 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-powerpc-cross : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-powerpc-cross but 4.7.3-1ubuntu1cross0.7 is to be installed
 libx32stdc++6-4.8-dbg : Conflicts: libx32stdc++6-4.7-dbg but 4.7.3-7ubuntu3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
leo@leo-SVS1513M1RB:~/atomic$ sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 1):

libstdc++ is not a binary package name. Since a package matching the name libstdc++ isn't found, apt-get searches packages that match this regex, and therefore wants to install 4.4, 4.6, 4.7, and 4.8 and the associated -doc and -dbg files
Instead, the packages you are probably looking for libstdc++6